# ſ (long s) and hyphenation

Tags: xetex, luatex, unicode, hyphenation, german

I'm using UTF-8 so it is – if one is using the right font – no problem to implement the different types of s in older German texts (s, ſ, ß). Unfortunately the hyphenation breaks because LaTeX does not know that ſ has to be dealt with just the same as it would do when dealing with "s".

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
XXX Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft

XXX Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft

\hyphenation{Ge-ſell-ſchaft}

XXX Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft

\end{document}
```

As one can see at the end of the line, I have to add the correct hyphenation manually. Any idea how I can solve this?

[image]

Comment: you could make this work automatically in luatex or xetex but in pdftex the best you could do is define ſ to always allow a hyphenation after it, it can not take part in `\patterns` or `\hyphenation`

Comment: your choices would be essentially to  (a) use `\hyphenation` as you have done for all necessary words or (b) copy the hyphenation patterns adding patterns for long s to match those for s and rebuild the xelatex format (lulatex does not need to be rebuilt) or (c) use `s` in the original markup and then set up font features (perhaps...) so that some s get typeset using the long form.  Which would you prefer? (the last probably depends on the font you use)

Comment: I use XeLaTeX, so copying the patterns is definitely the way to go. I'll look it up, right now I'm not sure how it works. (c) is a creative solution but does not work as I have parts where I want the long s and parts were I don't as I have to stay true to the source

Comment: oh or if you are using luatex then (d) implement a Lua hyphenation callback that hyphenates using s, then switches to long s and re-inserts the hyphenation points,

Comment: If the list of problematic patterns is short, in luatex you can also add them with `\babelpatterns` in the document itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For LuaTeX here is an implementation of David Carlisles idea to create a `hypenate` callback. It works by replacing every `ſ` with a marked `s` before hyphenation and then recovering the original characters after hyphenation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
local sattr = luatexbase.new_attribute("longsattr")
local disc = node.id'disc'
print('DISC', disc)

local function long_to_s(head, tail)
  for n in node.traverse(head) do
    if n == tail then break end
    if n.id == disc then
    print(n)
      long_to_s(n.pre)
      long_to_s(n.post)
      long_to_s(n.replace)
    end
    if n.char == 383 then
      n.char = 115
      node.set_attribute(n, sattr, 383)
    end
  end
end
local function s_to_long(head, tail)
  for n in node.traverse(head) do
    if n == tail then break end
    if n.id == disc then
      s_to_long(n.pre)
      s_to_long(n.post)
      s_to_long(n.replace)
    end
    local a = node.get_attribute(n, sattr)
    if a then
      n.char = a
      node.unset_attribute(n, sattr)
    end
  end
end
local function myhyph(head, tail)
  long_to_s(head, tail)
  lang.hyphenate(head, tail)
  s_to_long(head, tail)
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("hyphenate",myhyph,"hyphenate with modified s")
\end{luacode*}
\begin{document}
XXX Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft

XXX Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft
\end{document}
```

[image]

LuaTeX also allows you to manipulate the hyphenation pattern during a run, so you can also use (this is an automated version of David Carlisles choice (b)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
  local l = lang.new(tex.language)
  l:patterns(l:patterns():gsub('s', 'ſ'))
\end{luacode*}
\begin{document}
XXX Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft

XXX Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft Geſellſchaft
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I accept this answer as it seems a clever solution (even though, for other reasons, I stick to XeLaTeX)

Comment: This gives me a panic, unprotected Lua call ...

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to do this is to choose a font that supports ſ as an open type character variant, e.g., EB Garamond. Then you can just select that variant when you need it.

(Re-reading the comments above, I see this corresponds to option (c) from David Carlisle, which you said wasn't suitable, but this MWE shows you can have both kinds of s with this method.)

**Update** showing iſt and ſelbes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{EB Garamond}
\begin{document}
XXX Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft

\addfontfeature{CharacterVariant=1}

XXX Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft Gesellschaft

ist selbes
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're right about the font. Though dis is not exactly David Carlisles option c and is no proper way to do it, because though all ſ are s, not all s are ſ. The rule is, i think, that at the beginning of a word and in between letters it's an ſ – if not a long vocal is right before it. So it's »iſt« and »ſelbes«.

Comment: @MartinMueller, EB Garamond does not change it at the end of a word, but I think it changes it everywhere else. I'm not a German speaker though, so I do not know what it should be.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I've installed the EB Garamond but unfortunately the rules of ſ are far more complex than I knew (see wikipedia) and using your method does not produce the desired result. E.g. lesbisch should be lesbiſch but is rendered leſbiſch

Comment: @MartinMueller, that's a pity! The EB Garamond manual does warn that this feature isn't all that clever.