# Automatically replace s with ſ with LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, substitution

I am looking for a way to replace all s with ſ in my LuaTeX document (preferably plain LuaTeX or OpTeX) unless:

1. it is preceded by another s,
2. it is at the end of a word.

So it is similar to [rule based replacement of s with ſ (long s)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549562/rule-based-replacement-of-s-with-%c5%bf-long-s) but with fewer and simpler rules and using plain.

I tried the following code:

```
\fontfam[LM Fonts]

\directlua{%
function replace_s_with_long_s(input)
        return input:gsub("s", "ſ"):gsub("ſſ", "ß")
end
callback.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", replace_s_with_long_s)}

\lipsum[1]

\bye
```

running the `optex long-s.tex` command but there are two issues with it:

1. the s in lipsum got replaced (I want the substitution to affect only the text that is going to be typeset, not commands)
2. I don't know how you can match the last letter of a word in Lua (for rule 2).

As a reference, the text

```
pour qui sont ces serpents qui sifflent sur vos têtes
```

should become

```
pour qui ſont ces ſerpents qui ſifflent ſur vos têtes
```

Ideally, the solution should not depend on the specific font used in the document.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Currently I am using \fontfam[LM Fonts] (this is from OpTeX), but I am willing to use Garamond in the future

Comment: @MarcelKrüger The only error I get when running "optex long-s.tex" is `! Undefined control sequence. l.9 \lipſum[1]`, so it does not fail for unrelated reasons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It leaves some edge cases, but you can start with

```
\fontfam[LM Fonts]

\directlua{
--[[ A list of characters which indicate a word break ]]
local non_word_chars = {
  [utf8.codepoint'.'] = true,
  [utf8.codepoint','] = true,
  [utf8.codepoint';'] = true,
  --[[ Add more here as appropriate ]]
}
--[[ A list of node types which indicate a word break ]]
local non_word_ids = {
  [node.id'glue'] = true,
  [node.id'rule'] = true,
  --[[ Add more here as appropriate ]]
}
local s = utf8.codepoint's'
local long_s = utf8.codepoint'ſ'
function replace_s_with_long_s(head)
  local after_s = false
  for n in node.traverse(head) do
    local char, id = node.is_char(n)
    if char == s then
      local after = n.next
      local after_char, after_id = node.is_char(n.next)
      local is_end_of_word = after == nil or non_word_chars[after_char] or non_word_ids[after_id]
      if not (after_s or is_end_of_word) then
        n.char = long_s
      end
      after_s = true
    elseif char or non_word_ids[id] then
      after_s = false
    end
  end
  return true
end
callback.add_to_callback("pre_shaping_filter", replace_s_with_long_s)}

\lipsum[1]

\bye
```

The basic idea: Avoid `process_input_buffer` since otherwise you are transforming the input and not the typeset text, leading to issues like you had with `\lipſum`. Instead you can iterate over node lists using e.g. the `pre_shaping_filter` callback which runs directly before font processing is done. Then you just have to find character nodes with the `.char` field set to the Unicode codepoint of `s`. You can track if you already are just after a replacement with a simple boolean, but identifying the end of a work is more tricky: This code uses a simple heuristic using the following node type or character, but the lists should probably be extended and depending on the language the end of a word might be more complicated anyway.

Three of the remaining issues:

1. What is the end of a word? https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries is the standard algorithm to determine that in Unicode, but implementing that is somewhat involved.
2. How should combining marks be handled? E.g. should an `ś` also be replaced. Currently it depends on how it was input (precomposed or decomposed), but they probably should be handled consistently.
3. `s` inside of explicit `\discretionary` is ignored.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, the third issue is the only one that could be problematic to my use case, I will take it into account, thanks again